# Vagrant, nginx 404 - fastcgi sent in stderr unable to open primary script

Tags: nginx, php-fpm, vagrant

Was googleing a lot of and didn't find solution for this. Have found few accepted answers here on stackoverflow, but they didn't helped me.

I am using vagrant for development, or at least trying to use it. Have install it without a problem, but when I try to run a website, I am getting 404, my guess is that this is more nginx issue, rather then vagrant issue.

I have added to my windows host 127.0.0.1 lara.dev

This is my nginx site config below:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name lara.dev;
    root C:/xampp/htdocs/lara/public;

    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    charset utf-8;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    access_log off;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/lara.dev-error.log error;

    error_page 404 /index.php;

    sendfile off;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 16k;
        fastcgi_buffers 4 16k;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

In log file I am getting this:

```
FastCGI sent in stderr: "Unable to open primary script: /usr/share/nginx/C:/xampp/htdocs/lara/public/index.php (No such file or directory)" while reading response header from upstream, client: 10.0.2.2, server: lara.dev, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock:", host: "lara.dev:8000"
```

and my homestead file

```
---
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 1

authorize: C:/Users/Tim/.ssh/general.pub

keys:
    - C:/Users/Tim/.ssh/general

folders:
    - map: C:/xampp/htdocs/
      to: /home/vagrant/html

sites:
    - map: lara.dev
      to: /home/vagrant/html/lara/public/

databases:
    - homestead

variables:
    - key: APPLICATION_ENV
      value: env-localhost
```

Vagrant file:

```
require 'json'
require 'yaml'

VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"

homesteadYamlPath = File.expand_path("~/.homestead/Homestead.yaml")
afterScriptPath = File.expand_path("~/.homestead/after.sh")
aliasesPath = File.expand_path("~/.homestead/aliases")

require_relative 'scripts/homestead.rb'

Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
    if File.exists? aliasesPath then
        config.vm.provision "file", source: aliasesPath, destination: "~/.bash_aliases"
    end

    Homestead.configure(config, YAML::load(File.read(homesteadYamlPath)))

    if File.exists? afterScriptPath then
        config.vm.provision "shell", path: afterScriptPath
```

end
end

This is more likely that something is wrong with config for php5-fpm. But what, I do not know. Tnx in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the output:

> Unable to open primary script: /usr/share/nginx/C:/xampp/htdocs/lara/public/index.php (No such file or directory)

It appears you're referencing Windows-style paths (`C:/`), but running nginx on a Linux virtual machine (`/usr/share/nginx`). By default, Vagrant [shares only one folder](https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/synced-folders/), which is the project folder on your host machine (Windows) and `/vagrant` on your guest machine (Linux).

Your guest machine cannot access unshared folders, therefore neither can nginx.

Most Vagrant-based projects place the app's contents in the root of the project folder, in which case you could change the `root` directive to:

```
root /vagrant
```

If your project lives within a folder named `app`:

```
root /vagrant/app
```

You could also choose to map more folders by editing your `Vagrantfile`, restarting the guest machine, and then using your new synced folders in `root`.

Comment: Hi, thank you for response, I tried to edit Homestead file, not sure how to edit properly vagrant file, I have update my question with new code.

Comment: Tried also to change root path to /home/vagrant/html/lara/public/ but still doesn't work, of course I have restarted server.

Comment: Problem was in the path. server root path was wrong.